# Generate one single migration from all migration files symfony doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-migrations

My website is hosted on shared server so I cant run migration command since I dont have access to ssh.
Is there any way I can generate one single migration/sql file from all migration files generated during development, so that I can easily import/execute manually?

**I am using Symfony 2 framework with Doctrine2**

Comment: You can run commands from PHP level. For example you could try out ConsoleBundle https://github.com/CoreSphere/ConsoleBundle

Comment: The migrations are supposed to modify and take care of data loss after deployment of the live DB. If you are importing the DB you have a working DB. I don't see the problem in your question

Comment: @StivenLlupa I am not importing the db but schema changes and both database differ in data so I cant just replace database every time schema changes, dragoste's solution seems fine for this.

Comment: @reverbnation I really don't understand your question :P but as long as you found an answer that is fine by me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Output SQL and execute manually

You could [output the SQL of the migrations](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-migrations/en/latest/reference/managing_migrations.html#writing-migration-sql-files) to run on your local machine and then execute it from a web-console (e.g. phpMyAdmin).

```
php app/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --write-sql -e prod
```

Where the "`prod`" environment point towards a database where its structure is in sync with the one on your server.
Once you successfully ran the compiled SQL on your server, just re-run the same command to update your "local" version of the database (without the `--write-sql` option)

```
php app/console doctrine:migrations:migrate  -e prod
```

This will update your remote database without the need for SSH, with a direct connection to the (My)SQL server.

Upon next database change; repeat...

### Just point towards your production database

If possible, just point towards your production/remote database for your "`prod`" environment.

```
database_host: <your-website-domain>
database_port: 3306 #default
database_name: <your-database-name>
database_user: <your-database-user>
database_password: <your-database-password>
```

But most shared-hosting companies will not allow you to connect directly to the database from an external connection, then your stuck with the proposition mentioned above.